# How to use Form Handlers in OroCRM?

Tags: symfony, orocrm

I am creating bundle under ***OroCRM*** application. As per OroCRM folder structure there is handler file under form/ Handler folder under bundle and also there is provider file.

What does the handler and provider file do?

Answer (score 0):

This folder structure is arbitrary, it varies. Not every bundle would have form handlers or any kind of providers.

Form **handlers** are responsible for handling form submissions.

Responsibility of **providers** varies as well - there could be a provider responsible for providing a collection of available options for a drop-down (select) field, a provider responsible for providing currently set values for editing, etc.